# Creating hierarchical personal thesaurus using GeoNetwork

Tags: geonetwork, rdf

I need to do a hierarchical personal thesaurus in GeoNetwork 3.10, but I don’t find specific information about that. In the GeoNetwork user manual I only found information about normal personal thesaurus (like concepts list), but not hierarchical. I need to create a hierarchical personal thesaurus where I can update keywords, so in agreement with the GeoNetwork documentation I would need a personal thesaurus but I am not sure. Where can in find detailed information about this situation?

I have this local thesaurus (see xml content)

XML File

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:ns3="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:ns5="http://www.opengis.net/gml#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://geonetwork-opensource.org/probe">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme" />
                  <ns3:title>probe</ns3:title>
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#f690140a-fd04-4eb1-88ac-7d8d392fe4c8">
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9uqbagx1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9uqbagx1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#a1f852d4-d07b-4da1-9785-e80b1609967f">
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Environmental valuation</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Environmental valuation</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Valoración ambiental</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9usfh9x1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9usfh9x1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9uu45ix1">
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#f690140a-fd04-4eb1-88ac-7d8d392fe4c8">
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Agroecología</ns2:scopeNote>
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#7b2f0f55-46b7-4aae-8fe9-a73033ca3fe8">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Política pública ambiental</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Environmental public policy</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Environmental public policy</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Política pública ambiental</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9ut5jux1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9ut5jux1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#45be292f-72c1-409e-97c3-319c07393dd7">
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9uu45ix1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9uu45ix1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#5df338fc-1f04-4e24-8526-b05e82c4b0d3">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Ecología, conflictos ambinetales y territorio</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Ecology, environmental conflicts and territory</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Ecology, environmental conflicts and territory</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Ecología, conflictos ambinetales y territorio</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9utlv7x1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9utlv7x1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#38085e6c-6cf2-491a-8499-095492e065e3">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Salud pública</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Public health</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Public health</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Salud pública</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9uqqncx1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9uqqncx1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9utlv7x1">
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#5512a99f-c656-4c6f-bbfc-74e27e4605be">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Estudios ambientales</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Environmental studies</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Environmental studies</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Estudios ambientales</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9urabmx1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9urabmx1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9utlv7x1">
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9uu45ix1">
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#59eb7d46-5ae4-46bd-84db-41c462826509">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Valoración económica</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Economic valuation</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Economic valuation</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Valoración económica</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9us2okx1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9us2okx1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9uu45ix1">
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#45be292f-72c1-409e-97c3-319c07393dd7">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#a1f852d4-d07b-4da1-9785-e80b1609967f">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Valoración ambiental</ns2:prefLabel>
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#f690140a-fd04-4eb1-88ac-7d8d392fe4c8">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Agroecología</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Agroecology</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Agroecology</ns2:scopeNote>
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#123454b8-e805-4cc2-800c-b029136ea99e">
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Agricultural environmental studies</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Estudios ambientales agrarios</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9uvpg8x1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9uvpg8x1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#2ee939f3-ba4b-4549-8246-dc51955ced76">
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Environmental conflict C</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Conflicto ambiental C</ns2:scopeNote>
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#59c61e28-dcc8-4f2b-9108-9274acc2557f">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#2ee939f3-ba4b-4549-8246-dc51955ced76">
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9v11ndx1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#123454b8-e805-4cc2-800c-b029136ea99e">
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Agricultural environmental studies</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Estudios ambientales agrarios</ns2:prefLabel>
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#59c61e28-dcc8-4f2b-9108-9274acc2557f">
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9v087ux1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9v087ux1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9v11ndx1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#8c4851c6-5eaa-46ce-8079-66d990ea5907">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Conflicto ambiental B</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Environmental conflict B</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Environmental conflict B</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Conflicto ambiental B</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9v0lc0x1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9v0lc0x1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9v11ndx1">
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#2ee939f3-ba4b-4549-8246-dc51955ced76">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#45be292f-72c1-409e-97c3-319c07393dd7">
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Estudios impacto ambiental</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="fi" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="it" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="ca" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="pt" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Environmental impact studies</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="is" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="nl" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="zh" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="cs" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="sk" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="de" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="ru" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="fr" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="ko" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="it" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="zh" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="nl" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="ca" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Environmental impact studies</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Estudios impacto ambiental</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="fi" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="is" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="pt" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="sk" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="fr" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="de" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="ru" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="ko" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="cs" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#c2ff7bab-9107-4e50-8eb5-d9f3ca5599b2">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Economía y ambiente</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Economy and environment</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Economy and environment</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Economía y ambiente</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns5:BoundedBy rdf:nodeID="node1em9uvbpox1" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1em9uvbpox1">
                  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml#Envelope" />
                  <ns5:lowerCorner />
                  <ns5:upperCorner />
                  <ns5:srsName rdf:resource="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#epsg:4326" />
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#2ee939f3-ba4b-4549-8246-dc51955ced76">
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Conflicto ambiental C</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Environmental conflict C</ns2:prefLabel>
               </rdf:Description>
               <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://myhost:8081/thesaurus/theme/probe#59c61e28-dcc8-4f2b-9108-9274acc2557f">
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Conflicto ambiental A</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="fi" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="it" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="ca" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="pt" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Environmental conflict A</ns2:prefLabel>
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="is" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="nl" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="zh" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="cs" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="sk" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="de" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="ru" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="fr" />
                  <ns2:prefLabel xml:lang="ko" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="it" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="zh" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="nl" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="ca" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Environmental conflict A</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="es">Conflicto ambiental A</ns2:scopeNote>
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="fi" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="is" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="pt" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="sk" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="fr" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="de" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="ru" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="ko" />
                  <ns2:scopeNote xml:lang="cs" />
               </rdf:Description>
            </rdf:RDF>
```

I can’t enable the relationed terms function, and I don’t find where I can enable it.

[image]

I need to add 2 group levels more (hierarchical ), but I don't find where and how do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use SKOS which allows you to define narrower and broader terms.  Here's an example screenshot of a term from a hierarchical thesaurus that was imported into GeoNetwork

[image: detail from GeoNetwork view of a hierarchical thesaurus]

The RDF might look like (there are several ways of structuring this):

```
<rdf:Description
    rdf:about="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/lithology/acidic_igneous_rock">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept"/>
    <rdfs:seeAlso xml:lang="en">siliceous igneous rock</rdfs:seeAlso>
    <dc:source>after LeMaitre et al. 2002</dc:source>
    <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/lithology/igneous_rock"/>
    <skos:broader 
      rdf:resource="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/lithology/acidic_igneous_material"/>
    <skos:definition xml:lang="en">Igneous rock with more than 63 percent SiO2.</skos:definition>
    <skos:exactMatch rdf:resource="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/lithology/0002"/>
    <skos:inScheme
      rdf:resource="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifierscheme/cgi/201211/simplelithology"/>
    <skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/lithology/granitoid"/>
    <skos:narrower
      rdf:resource="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/lithology/quartz_rich_igneous_rock"/>
    <skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/lithology/rhyolitoid"/>
    <skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://resource.geosciml.org/classifier/cgi/lithology/dacite"/>
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">acidic igneous rock</skos:prefLabel>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: I followed the indications, and i used basic SKOS, and finally the result was satisfactory.